# ReactJS SVG marker elements does not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

by these [docs](https://svgwg.org/specs/markers/#MarkerElement) the following code should create the output that is in the docs:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200">

   <defs>
     <marker id="Square" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10"
             refX="5" refY="5" orient="auto">
       <path d="M 5,1 L 9,5 5,9 1,5 z" fill="#6a9100"/>
     </marker>
     <marker id="Circle" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10"
             refX="5" refY="5" orient="auto">
       <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" fill="dodgerblue"/>
     </marker>
   </defs>

   <path d="M 100,50 C 100,250 500,-50 300,150"
         fill="none" stroke="deeppink" stroke-width="3">
     <marker href="#Square" position="0"/>
     <marker href="#Square" position="100%"/>
     <marker href="#Circle" position="50px"/>
     <marker href="#Circle" position="calc(100% - 50px)"/>
     <marker refX="5" refY="5" position="50%">
       <!-- the cross -->
       <path d="M 3,3 L 7,7 M 3,7 L 7,3"
             fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
     </marker>
   </path>
</svg>
```

but this does not work.
codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-brook-2clmj?file=/src/App.js:51-1133).

it seems that react does not support child `<markers />` elements
but referencing marker element by URL reference does work. this is pretty stupid - what if I don't want to predefine each marker element in the `defs` section and I want to render it on the fly?
any help???

here i will be specific - it seems that react does not support `position` property of the marker element (i know this because of typescript warning)- so how do i set the position?

Comment: SVG in general does not support position. What uses the Square and Circle markers?

Comment: you can reference `marker` element by reference to a marker element defined in a `defs` section or render it directly inside `path` for example - if you do so there marker is considered <i>positioned marker</i>.  if this is positioned marker so you can define it by give it `position` property. please see the docs ,  and the provided codesandbox.

Comment: Here an example of `<marker/>` element from MDN docs - and it works with react: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sound-zde0f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The marker href and position properties are new in SVG 2. No browser has implemented them and I don't think we have any plans to do so. I imagine they will be dropped from SVG 2.

Comment: no fellows - these are called `vertex markers` which you can reference by the `marker-start` `marker-mid` and `marker-end` attributes.  i have a case that i don't know how my marker is going to be so i cant predefine it. i need `positioned marker`. like the example i provided in the codesandbox. 
the example in MDN working for me also - but she is useless because i don't know how my arrow is going to look before i receive my properties.

Comment: @RobertLongson so the problem React supports only SVG 1.1 and not 2(and also the browsers)?

Comment: React is not relevant here. Browsers support most of SVG 1.1 and some of the additional parts of SVG 2 (which is mostly a superset of SVG 1.1)

Comment: so i have to predefine any marker that i maybe may use and reference the correct one? this is pretty ugly solution

Comment: @RobertLongson can you please help me with an alternative to marker element for creating arrowheads? i will very appreciate it because I'm pretty stuck here.

Comment: Do it the way everybody else does it, define markers in defs and reference them in CSS.

Comment: but i cant define marker for any optional `arrowSize` or `color` or `orient`. how can i solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211750/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-eliav-louski).